# Evaluating $j$-invariant in PARI/GP.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, math-software, class-field-theory

> Is there any command to evaluate $j$-invariant in PARI/GP?

In Pari/Gp reference card there is $\operatorname{ellj}(x)$ function; but I am not understanding how to evaluate  $j(i)$ or $j(\sqrt{-2})$.

Any hint is also welcome; Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what it says on the tin. One evaluates $j(x+iy)$ with the command `ellj(x+I*y)`. Sample:

[image]

This gives $j(i)=1728$, $j(\sqrt{-2})=8000$, $j(e^{\frac 23 \pi i}) = 0$.

Comment: Mike Miller Thank you very much

Comment: so can we find quotient of Dedekind eta function in Pari

Comment: @Sushma `eta(x)` is the Dedekind eta function. If you don't want the leading $q^{1/24}$ included, then instead use `eta(x,0)`.

Comment: @ Mike Miller thank you very much